# Numpy, vectorized function on multiple label masks

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following code for replacing each value of an image with the median (or any other function) value based on masks from a labels image created in a segmentation step. It feels as if the for loop can be vectorized. What is the best approach do do this?

I looked at building a separate index array for each label, but ultimately did not see how this would help.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage import data, io

def create_segment_image(original_image, labels_image):
    segment_image = np.zeros(original_image.shape, original_image.dtype)

    for label in np.unique(labels_image):
        segment_image[labels_image==label] = np.median(original_image[labels_image==label], axis=0)

    return segment_image

if __name__ == '__main__':

    original_image = data.astronaut()
    labels_image = slic(original_image, n_segments=1000, max_iter=10, compactness=7, sigma=1, convert2lab=True, enforce_connectivity=True, min_size_factor=0.1, max_size_factor=3, slic_zero=False)
    segment_image = create_segment_image(original_image, labels_image)
    # io.imsave('images/segment_image.png', segment_image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about vectorizing the innermost loop. The call to `median` calculates over a different number of elements each time, which would make it hard to put all of the calls into a single array.

On the other hand there's some fairly low hanging fruit in terms of how you're choosing the elements by label. You find the indices for each label twice in your original function, calculating the index array only once knocks about 25% off the runtime

```
def create_segment_image_2(original_image, labels_image):
    segment_image = np.zeros(original_image.shape, original_image.dtype)
    for label in np.unique(labels_image):
        inds = np.where(labels_image == label)
        segment_image[inds] = np.median(original_image[inds], axis=0)    
    return segment_image
```

You can get even bigger improvements by sorting the array indexes by label, then taking advantage of that sorting to chose the image elements to median over. Replacing the many searches with a single sort gives about a factor of 20 speedup.

```
def create_segment_image_3(original_image, labels_image):
    segment_image = np.zeros(original_image.shape, original_image.dtype)
    # sort the indices by their labels
    labelinds = np.argsort(labels_image, None)
    labels = np.unique(labels_image)
    # use the searchsorted to find the indices for each label
    rights = np.searchsorted(labels_image.flatten(), labels, side='right', sorter=labelinds)
    left = 0
    for right in rights:
        # choose our block of the image array
        inds = labelinds[left:right]
        # convert back to a two dimensional index array
        inds = [inds // original_image.shape[1], inds % original_image.shape[1]]
        segment_image[inds] = np.median(original_image[inds], axis=0)
        # update our boundaries
        left = right
    return segment_image
```

Benchmarking in ipython

```
In [54]: %timeit create_segment_image(original_image, labels_image)
2.15 s ± 29.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [55]: %timeit create_segment_image_2(original_image, labels_image)
1.48 s ± 4.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [56]: %timeit create_segment_image_3(original_image, labels_image)
121 ms ± 561 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Confirming that our new solutions give the same result as the old one.

```
In [57]: np.all(create_segment_image_2(original_image, labels_image) == create_segment_image(original_image, labels_image))
Out[57]: True

In [58]: np.all(create_segment_image_3(original_image, labels_image) == create_segment_image(original_image, labels_image))
Out[58]: True
```

Comment: Many thaks for the detailled answer! Especially for the demo of how to utilise the sorting, the time saving is quite impressive! This is a cool trick to know and will come in handy in other situations. Thanks.